# How can I target these tds in css?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

For example, this is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Don't target this<td>
        <td>Target this<td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Target this<td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Target this<td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

And in my css I don't want to target `tr:first-child > td:first-child`

How can this be achieved with `:not()` selector?

For example this is not working

```
table {
    tr:not(:first-child) {
        // eliminates entire child
    }
}
```

and

```
table {
    tr {
        td:not(:first-child) {
            // eliminates all tds that are first-child
         }
     }
 }
```

EDIT: I know I can use `:last-child()`, but want to achieve this with `:not()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the `last-child` of each row

```css
tr > td:last-child {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Don't target this</td>
    <td>Target this</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Target this</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Target this</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And in case you will have many columns you will need at least two selectors:

```css
tr:not(:first-child) > td,
tr:first-child > td:not(:first-child){
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Don't target this</td>
    <td>Target this</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Target this</td>
    <td>Target this</td>
    <td>Target this</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Target this</td>
    <td>Target this</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, should have written it above. I know, but I want to use `.not()`. Is there a way?

Comment: Ugh, ugly.. :D Thanks, will go with `last-child()` :)

Comment: @dututu is there any reason to use not() ? because you shouldn't first decide what to use and apply it, you should see your example and try to find the best thing to use.